# Simulate API 29 Vibrations in 26 and below

Tags: android, android-vibration

I want to simulate API 29 vibration effects:

```
EFFECT_CLICK
EFFECT_DOUBLE_CLICK
EFFECT_HEAVY_CLICK
EFFECT_TICK
```

in version 26 and lower as well. Does anybody know how these translate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I did. I am only covering two types of vibrations which will have to do. A longer single one and two short ones, which may translate to CLICK and DOUBLE_CLICK:

```
private void vibrate(int vibrationMessageId) {

    long[] doubleClickPattern = {0, 75, 75, 75};

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        Log.d(TAG, "vibrate: SDK 26+ " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);

        switch (vibrationMessageId) {
            case Constants.VIBRATION_HEAVY_CLICK:
                ((Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(200, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
                break;
            case Constants.VIBRATION_DOUBLE_CLICK:
                ((Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(VibrationEffect.createWaveform(doubleClickPattern,-1));
                break;
        }


    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "vibrate: SDK <26 " + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);

        switch (vibrationMessageId) {
            case Constants.VIBRATION_HEAVY_CLICK:
                ((Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(200);
                break;
            case Constants.VIBRATION_DOUBLE_CLICK:

                ((Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(doubleClickPattern,-1);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I also wanted to recreate these vibration patterns, so I did some trial and error to get these numbers. They are as close to what I felt was right.

```
    val singleClickPattern = longArrayOf(0, 10)
    val singleClickAmplitude = intArrayOf(0, 180)

    val doubleClickPattern = longArrayOf(0, 10, 160, 10)
    val doubleClickAmplitude = intArrayOf(0, 255, 0, 255)

    val heavyClickPattern = longArrayOf(0, 13)
    val heavyClickAmplitude = intArrayOf(0, 255)

    val tickPattern = longArrayOf(0, 5)
    val tickAmplitude = intArrayOf(0, 50)
```

Using them like this:

```
    vibrationEffect = VibrationEffect.createWaveform(tickPattern, tickAmplitude, -1)
    vibrator.vibrate(vibrationEffect);
```

You can try them out yourself by looping through the predefined ones and these ones.

Answer (score 0):

It is more or less h/w compatibility.

2 things here,

1. VibrationEffect is already added in Api Level 26
   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/VibrationEffect
2. Vibrator is deprecated from Api Level 26 & VibrationEffect comes into play as mentioned above
   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html#vibrate(long%5B%5D,%20int)

Comment: I saw those. I was really looking for some way to translate the most recent effects (API 29) to make them as backward compatible as possible. Closest I could come is the update I posted.